# Create a specific json(Hash) from a csv using Ruby

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, csv, hash

I would appreciate any help trying to create a multi faceted CSV (with header) into a json I can use for a post.  Here is csv and JSON format required.  Ultimately; I need to create a single location that may have 1, 2, or many fax machines.

csv

```
ID,Location Name,timezone,code,display,address,city,state,postalcode,country,faxlocation,faxnumber,(in)active
5,Location1,America/Chicago,bu,Building,1313 Mocking Bird Lane,The City,IL,999999,USA,Room 1; Room 2,111111111; 2222222222,active
8,Location2,America/New_York,bu,Building,2626 Humpty Dumpty Lane,Another City,NY,999999,USA,Room 1; Room 2; Room 3,111111111; 2222222222; 3333333333,active
32,Location3,America/Los_Angeles,bu,Building,3939 Big Bird Lane,Last City,CA,999999,USA,Room 1,111111111,active
```

json

```
{
    "resourceType": "Location",
    "id": "5",
     "description": "America/Chicago",
    "name": "Location1",
    "address": {
        "address": "1313 Mocking Bird Lane",
        "city": "The City",
        "state": "IL",
        "postalCode": "999999",
        "country": "USA"
    },
    "telecom": [
        {
           "system": "fax",
            "value": "1111111111",
            "use": "work",
            "extension": [
                {
                    "url": "displayValue",
                    "valueString": "Room 1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
           "system": "fax",
            "value": "2222222222",
            "use": "work",
            "extension": [
                {
                    "url": "displayValue",
                    "valueString": "Room "
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "active"
}
```

all requires here

```
locations = CSV.read(csv)

locations.shift # remove header row
locations.each_index do |index|
    faxnumarrat = locations[index][10].to_s.delete(' ').split(';') #Take 10th index and turn it into an array
    faxlocarray = locations[index][11].to_s.delete(' ').split(';') #Take 11th index and turn it into an array

    # keys = ['loc1','loc2'] 
    # values = ['fax1','fax2']
   my_hash = Hash[faxnumarray.zip(faxlocarray)] # Combine locations and fax numbers

   my_hash.each do |key, value|

      @fax_hash = { 'system' => 'fax', 'value' => key, 'use' => 'work', 'extension' => [{ 'url' => 'automaticSend', 'valueBoolean' => false }, { 'url' => 'displayValue', 'valueString' => value }] } #Build up a hash using k,v.  ISSUE:  Only creates one fax.  Need to put all faxes associated no matter how many per location
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reading in the entire CSV as an array of arrays, you instead can `open`
or create a `new` CSV instance and pass in an option to convert the first line of
into headers into keys to access columns within a row more easily; e.g.

```
locations = CSV.open(csv, headers: true)

location = locations.first
# => #<CSV::Row "ID":"5" "Location Name":"Location1" "timezone":"America/Chicago" "code":"bu" "display":"Building" "address":"1313 Mocking Bird Lane" "city":"The City" "state":"IL" "postalcode":"999999" "country":"USA" "faxlocation":"Room 1; Room 2" "faxnumber":"111111111; 2222222222" "(in)active":"active">

location["Location Name"]
# => "Location1"
```

With the headers as keys we can use, we can then build a new Hash object using
those old values, whilst also build a collection they you had started in your
question example

```
locations = CSV.open(csv, headers: true)

results = locations.map.with_index do |location, index|
  faxnumarray = location["faxnumber"].delete(' ').split(';') #Take 10th index and turn it into an array
  faxlocarray = location["faxlocation"].delete(' ').split(';') #Take 11th index and turn it into an array

  # keys = ['loc1','loc2']
  # values = ['fax1','fax2']
  my_hash = Hash[faxnumarray.zip(faxlocarray)] # Combine locations and fax numbers

  {
    "resourceType" => "Location",
    "id" => location["ID"],
    "description" => location["timezone"],
    "name" => location["Location Name"],
    "address" => {
      "address" => location["address"],
      "city" => location["city"],
      "state" => location["state"],
      "postalCode" => location["postalcode"],
      "country" => location["country"]
    },
    "telecom" => my_hash.map do |key, value|
      {
        'system' => 'fax',
        'value' => key,
        'use' => 'work',
        'extension' => [
          {
            'url' => 'automaticSend',
            'valueBoolean' => false
          },
          {
            'url' => 'displayValue',
            'valueString' => value
          }
        ]
      }
    end,
    "status" => location["(in)active"]
  }
end

results.to_json
```

I reused your code where I could and made the last object (the returned object)
within the `map` block resemble the requested Hash result object. Using `map`
instead of `each` means it

> Returns a new array with the results of running *block* once for every element in *enum*.
>
> -- [Module: Enumerable (Ruby 2_4_0)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

This produces the following result

```
[
  {
    "resourceType": "Location",
    "id": "5",
    "description": "America/Chicago",
    "name": "Location1",
    "address": {
      "address": "1313 Mocking Bird Lane",
      "city": "The City",
      "state": "IL",
      "postalCode": "999999",
      "country": "USA"
    },
    "telecom": [
      {
        "system": "fax",
        "value": "111111111",
        "use": "work",
        "extension": [
          {
            "url": "automaticSend",
            "valueBoolean": false
          },
          {
            "url": "displayValue",
            "valueString": "Room 1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "system": "fax",
        "value": "2222222222",
        "use": "work",
        "extension": [
          {
            "url": "automaticSend",
            "valueBoolean": false
          },
          {
            "url": "displayValue",
            "valueString": " Room 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "status": "active"
  },
  {
    "resourceType": "Location",
    "id": "8",
    "description": "America/New_York",
    "name": "Location2",
    "address": {
      "address": "2626 Humpty Dumpty Lane",
      "city": "Another City",
      "state": "NY",
      "postalCode": "999999",
      "country": "USA"
    },
    "telecom": [
      {
        "system": "fax",
        "value": "111111111",
        "use": "work",
        "extension": [
          {
            "url": "automaticSend",
            "valueBoolean": false
          },
          {
            "url": "displayValue",
            "valueString": "Room 1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "system": "fax",
        "value": "2222222222",
        "use": "work",
        "extension": [
          {
            "url": "automaticSend",
            "valueBoolean": false
          },
          {
            "url": "displayValue",
            "valueString": " Room 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "system": "fax",
        "value": "3333333333",
        "use": "work",
        "extension": [
          {
            "url": "automaticSend",
            "valueBoolean": false
          },
          {
            "url": "displayValue",
            "valueString": " Room 3"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "status": "active"
  },
  {
    "resourceType": "Location",
    "id": "32",
    "description": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "name": "Location3",
    "address": {
      "address": "3939 Big Bird Lane",
      "city": "Last City",
      "state": "CA",
      "postalCode": "999999",
      "country": "USA"
    },
    "telecom": [
      {
        "system": "fax",
        "value": "111111111",
        "use": "work",
        "extension": [
          {
            "url": "automaticSend",
            "valueBoolean": false
          },
          {
            "url": "displayValue",
            "valueString": "Room 1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "status": "active"
  }
]
```

**References:**

- [Class: CSV (Ruby 2_4_0)](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

Comment: Simply awesome.  Works like a champ.  Thanks for taking me to school and teaching me something new!